# Tensorflow while loop runs only once

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

The below while loop should print `"\n\nInside while..."` 10 times but when I run the graph, `"\n\nInside while..."` is printed exactly once. Why is that?

```
i = tf.constant(0)

def condition(i):
   return i < 10

def body(i):
    print("\n\nInside while...", str(i))
    return i + 1

r = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [i])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue comes from conflating TensorFlow graph building with graph execution.

The functions you pass to `tf.while_loop` get executed once, to generate the TensorFlow graph responsible for executing the loop itself. So if you had put a `tf.Print` in there (for example, saying `return tf.Print(i+1, [i+1])`) you'd see it print 10 times when the loop is actually executed by the TensorFlow system.

Answer (score 0):

I know practically nothing about TensorFlow and cannot help you with your immediate problem, but you can accomplish something similar (maybe) if you write your code differently. Following the logic of your program, a different implementation of `while_loop` was devised below. It takes your `condition` and `body` to run a while loop that has been parameterized with functions passed to it. Shown below is a conversation with the interpreter showing how this can be done.

```
>>> def while_loop(condition, body, local_data):
    while condition(*local_data):
        local_data = body(*local_data)
    return local_data

>>> i = 0
>>> def condition(i):
    return i < 10

>>> def body(i):
    print('Inside while', i)
    return i + 1,

>>> local_data = while_loop(condition, body, (i,))
Inside while 0
Inside while 1
Inside while 2
Inside while 3
Inside while 4
Inside while 5
Inside while 6
Inside while 7
Inside while 8
Inside while 9
>>> local_data
(10,)
>>>
```